# Jquery slider not displaying at all

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to display a slider on magentogo store but somehow despite copying all code from the demo example of slider along with css the slider is not working. The css is set to display none as this is how slider works. But Jquery is not calling the slider code in loop.js file. I am really stuck here so please help.
 I am using  slidesjs: 
[slidesjs.com](http://slidesjs.com)

and here is the website:
https://magoopaddleboards.gostorego.com/#

Edit I thought adding code will take too much place but as I got two down votes already here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s51e747ab4fd45.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/1e/74/7a/b4/fd/45/designeditor/theme/current/49/js_editor_files/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s51e747ab4fd45.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/1e/74/7a/b4/fd/45/designeditor/theme/current/49/js_editor_files/no.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s51e747ab4fd45.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/1e/74/7a/b4/fd/45/designeditor/theme/current/49/js_editor_files/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s51e747ab4fd45.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/1e/74/7a/b4/fd/45/designeditor/theme/current/49/js_editor_files/loop_2.js"></script>
```

As you can see I am including all required files. And the code in loop2_js is:

```
$(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 920,
        height: 362
      });
    });
```

And here is slides code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_44989/skin/frontend/default/theme182k/images/slider_pic3.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_44989/skin/frontend/default/theme182k/images/slider_pic4.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_44989/skin/frontend/default/theme182k/images/slider_pic1.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://livedemo00.template-help.com/magento_44989/skin/frontend/default/theme182k/images/slider_pic2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: IMHO - if you want help show us some Code. No enough information.

Comment: @Shumail92 code added

Comment: @chontamcslurpy code added

Comment: It seems a conflict in jquery to me. Do proper debugging and remove unnecessary .js from you code.

Answer (score 1):

The `$('#slides')` part returns `null`. So there is no slider script applied to anything.

You have a conflict in your jQuery somewhere.

**EDIT:** At `loop.js` make these changes:

```
$j(function() {
  $j('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 920,
    height: 362
  });
});
```

Comment: I guess start by pulling out unnecessary files. Such as `no.js`.

Comment: Ok I have removed the conflict by adding noconflict after prototype and the slider works now but it throws Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent'  @Stijn Martens any idea?

Comment: You should at least use the latest jQuery to begin with. `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`

Comment: I got it. Just put everything like it was before. But apply the code changes I provided in my current edit ^

Comment: Still the same after latest jquery

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Remember to restore everything like it was before.

Comment: Because sliderjs is using the `$` variable still. Replace all occurances of `$` in sliderjs for `$j`